# Is there any way to implement mutual authentication using SSL certificate configuration in iis server

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I am trying using self signed client and server certificate to host my web api in iis server.i am facing forbidden error after selecting client certificate.

Comment: Open IIS log files and read the status code, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: Do you mean you enabled the certificate auth and it show the 403 error?  I suggest you could try to checkyou have installed Server's cert issuer certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities under Local Computer on your IIS machine.